How do I make the pictures closer to eachother?
<div style="padding-inline: 200px;" align="center">
    
    <h2 style="font-size:4vw;">Melngalvju nams</h2> <br> <br>
    <h2 style="font-size:2vw;">Vēsture</h2>
    <p style="font-size:1.5vw;">Rīgas Melngalvju nams (vācu: Das Schwarzhäupterhaus) ir atjaunots 14.—19. gadsimta arhitektūras piemineklis, atrodas Vecrīgā pie Rātslaukuma. Celtne vairākkārt pārbūvēta, lielākās nama pārbūves notikušas 1580., 1619.—1625. un 1886. gadā. Otrā pasaules kara laikā nodedzis, 1999. gadā Melngalvju nams tika uzcelts no jauna. </p>

    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <img src="Vēsture01.jpg" alt="Melngalvju nams (pa kreisi) krievu sabombardētajā Rātslaukumā 1710. gada jūlijā" style="width: 35%;">
        <img src="Vēsture02.jpg" alt="Rīgas Melngalvju nams (labajā pusē) pēc sagraušanas 1941. gadā" style="width: 35%;">
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <h2 style="font-size:2vw;">Nosaukums</h2>
    <p style="font-size:1.5vw;">Celtnes nosaukums radies no tās īpašniekiem Melngalvju brālības, kuras galvenais simbols bija svētais Maurīcijs, pirmais melnais kristietis, kareivju un neprecētu vīriešu aizgādnis. Viņš redzams nama ģerbonī un ir attēlots pie tā ieejas.</p>
    
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <img src="Nosaukums01.jpg" alt="Rīgas Melngalvju nama portāls ar Svētās Marijas un Svētā Maurīcija ciļņiem" style="width: 35%;">
        <img src="Nosaukums02.jpg" alt="Melngalvju brālības svarīgākais simbols - svētajs Maurīcijs" style="width: 35%;">
    </div>
    <br> <br>
    <h2 style="font-size:2vw;">Arhitektūra</h2>
    <p style="font-size:1.5vw;">Pastāvēšanas laikā Melngalvju nams vairākkārt pārveidots, paplašināts un papildināts, tomēr nama abi zelmiņi daudz saglabājuši arī no pirmā un 15. gadsimta būves laika. Viduslaiku Livonijas laikā 14.—16. gadsimtā ēkai bija tā laika Hanzas pilsētu gotiskās celtniecības tradīcijām atbilstošs abu zelmiņu stateniskais akcentējums ar slaidām vienkāršu un profilētu ķieģeļu ierāmētām ielodzēm, ko noslēdza smails loks. Kopš 1522. gada ēkas ieeju rotāja Dievmātes un svētā Maurīcija attēli.</p>
   
    <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; margin-bottom: 20px;">
        <img src="Arhitektūra01.jpg" alt="Melngalvju nams 1924. gadā" style="width: 35%;">
        <img src="Arhitektūra02.jpg" alt="Melngalvju nama svētku zāle 19. gadsimta beigās" style="width: 35%;">
    </div>
    <br> <br>
</div

I have tried some things, but nothing has worked. Adjusting the width just makes the pictures bigger.
I looked for some thing online, but I didn't find anything useful.

Using 'space-between' in flex will separate elements by the maximum width possible, until it fills 100% width of the parent container.
If you want to explicitly set the space between elements, you can use the gap property
gap:20px

Try that out
